# Supabase: can't signUp email because logged in through OAuth

Tags: javascript, next.js, oauth, supabase

My email already exists because I signed in with google. I want to add additional login methods using email and password.

I use the function supabase.auth.signUp() but because the email already exists it fails.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: What error message are you getting when you call the `auth.signUp()` method?